# how to return 0 during count in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have tables "skill_rating" and "skill_description".
descriptionId column of skill_description is foreign key in skill_rating.
I want to count the number of staffId for each description with rating 2.

```
$query1=$this->db->select('skill_description.description, count(staffId) as experienced')
                       ->from('skill_rating')
                       ->join('skill_description','skill_rating.descriptionId = skill_description.descriptionId')
                       ->where_in ('skill_description.descriptionId',$id)
                       ->where ('skill_rating.rating','2')
                       ->group_by("skill_description.description")                       
                       ->order_by("skill_description.description asc")
                       ->get();
```

This only returns me results with description having non zero count meaning it does not gives count 0 for description with zero counts. i have tried coalesce but no difference.
i want result with 0 for descriptions that do not have rating 2.
what should i do?

Comment: how `staff_info` table  is related in  your query?

Comment: @pradeep i have edited the query now.

Comment: this will not work , if `staffId` is column from `staff_info` then you have to also `join` that table in your query

Comment: @pradeep staffId column is also in skill_rating table so i think it wont make any difference. plus i have also tried what u just said by joining staff_info table..but same result

Comment: ok let me try by joining this